# Why is my UIView drawing behind my other views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIView which is opened and closed by a button onscreen.  I am positioning it over a scrollable custom text area which is a bunch of UILabels added to a UIScrollView.

I've made sure that it is added last in my view hierarchy, in the xib.  I have also tried calling `bringSubviewToFront`, and have even removed the UIView from the parent view and re-added it after doing the layout.

Nothing that I have tried prevents it from being drawn behind this UIScrollView.  I have verified that my UIView is actually the last UIView in the hierarchy by looking at the view hierarchy in the debugger at runtime.

The UIView in question, shown as a smiley in the picture here, has children.  It has a 3x3 grid of invisible UIButtons, and a UIImageView to draw the image, which is normally something other than the smiley.  But I am operating on the parent UIView, not the children.

[image: Example of the problem I am seeing]

Is there anything I can try, to help diagnose this?  To recap, I have done all the following:

- the UIView is added last in my view hierarchy, after the UIScrollView.  It is a child of the same parent (the root view) as the scroll view - hence, a sibling view of the scroll view.
- after doing the layout, I've tried `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myView]`
- after doing the layout, I've tried doing `[myView removeFromSuperView]` followed by `[self.view addSubview:myView]`.

The latter two operations are performed at the very end of my layout method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding the subView using the `- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index` method. Index being `0`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622538-insertsubview?language=objc

Comment: Or maybe you have [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourScrollView] somewhere after layoutSubviews?